# How to avoid black screen during acitivy.recreate()

Tags: android

`requireActivity().recreate()`

I'm using above code after chainging locale. there's a black screen during `requireActivity().recreate()`  (for about 0.3sec).

I wanna change the black screen with splash screen or progress bar...

Is there any way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you call **requireActivity().recreate()** new instance of activity will be created and it takes some time so in this duration, you will see the default background of the window , you can change the defaults but it doest support progress bar , you can change the color and add a drawable to it which I think helps you enough
In order to remove the default black screen make a custom theme:
in drawable folder:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <!-- black background -->
        <solid android:color="@color/colorBlack" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- launcher icon -->
<item android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground" android:height="150dp" android:width="150dp" android:gravity="center" />
```

then configure it in your styles file:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/starting_screen</item>
```

hope it helped